# Creation Restful Web Service Using GET and POST method and returning with the XML

Tags: .net, rest

how to create a **restful webservice** using Get and Post method and returning with XML
please could help me as I am beginner of .NET

Comment: i wish you google first before posting something! http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426769/Creating-a-REST-service-using-ASP-NET-Web-API check this link

Comment: `</SummerOfLove>` People, for the love of all things good. PLEASE learn to do just a *tiny* bit of your own research before polluting StackOverflow with this nonsense.

Comment: Aha, googling really helps and it's a quicker way than sitting and waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you creating REST service - new and from scratch, then definitly one suggestion and most recent REST technology in Microsoft stack - ASP.NET Web API.

On [ASP.NET Web API official website](http://asp.net/web-api/) you can find many tutorials.

Start from the first one - [Your First ASP.NET Web API (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Comment: Is it an answer for you?